# Delphi ios scale Bitmap inside ImageControl

Tags: ios, delphi, tbitmap

I have 75*75 .png files, but I want them to show in a 150x150 sized ImageControl with transparent background. I currently use this code:

```
  FBitmapBufferLoadFromFile(...);
  icContactsDetails.Bitmap := TBitmap.Create(0, 0);
  icContactsDetails.Bitmap.Assign(FBitmapBuffer);
  icContactsDetails.Width := icContactsDetails.Bitmap.Width;
  icContactsDetails.Height := icContactsDetails.Bitmap.Height;
  icContactsDetails.Scale.X := 150 / icContactsDetails.Bitmap.Width;
  icContactsDetails.Scale.Y := 150 / icContactsDetails.Bitmap.Height;
```

I have the following questions:

1) How do I keep transparency? (Transparent area in .png is converted to white.)
2) Should I do the scaling outside the ImageControl to avoid setting width/height?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set

```
icContactsDetails.WrapMode:=TImageWrapMode.iwStretch
```

instead of scaling the control.

Comment: I upvoted. But TImageControl / TImageControl.Bitmap do not have a wrapmode property. But I think TImage does. Will do some research!

Comment: I prefer using TImage than TImageControl.

Comment: @slotomo, does Bitmap have a wrapMode property? I think you meant `icContactsDetails.WrapMode`

Comment: If you use TImage then TImage have property WrapMode, if you use other controls with Fill property like TRectangle then WrapMode in on TBrushBitmap.

Comment: I switched over to TImage now as well. And both problem sovled now using TImage + WrapMode property :)